# Android -CosmosDB : AzureData.getDocument() API call fails to return document

Tags: android, kotlin, azure-cosmosdb, document, lib

I am trying to integrate Cosmos DB in the android app using [AzureData client lib](https://github.com/Azure/Azure.Android/tree/master/azuredata)

I've successfully  configured `AzureData.Configure()` and  also created a database.
However, I am unable to access the document from the existing collection using the API `AzureData.getDocument()`.

This API is returning the error

```
{
  "code":"NotFound",
  "message":"Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system"
}
```

Could someone please help me with suggestions in this regard

The psuedo code is given below:

```
AzureData.configure(
            context,
            appData.appConfig.azureCosmosDB.DatabaseId,
            appData.appConfig.azureCosmosDB.PrimaryKey,
            PermissionMode.All /* or PermissionMode.Read */
        )

var isconfigured =  AzureData.isConfigured // true


 AzureData.getDocument(
                    "mydocId"
                    "partitionKey", 
                   " collectionId",
                    "databaseId",
                    CosmosDocument::class.java
                )
                {
                    var document = it.resource // return null
                    var error = it.error // returns error 
                }
```

Comment: as per my suggestions, connection  is not building

Comment: Is this a sample code or the same code which you are running because there is a space in your getDocument method's parameter "<space>collectionId".

Comment: No. I've removed the original  key values from the code.